# Which package should I use in Facebook-Graph-API?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get data from my facebook page posts such as likers names, number of likes, number of comments and global info about my account like the list of users liking my page, ...

I am a bit lost with the Facebook-Graph-API website because there are a lot of packages like Business SDK, Marketing API SDK, Pages API, ...

If someone has an idea of which API it would be very helpful !

Additional question : is it possible to use the facebook graph API with python ?

Thanks

Comment: this is a good start: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ - and of course it is possible to use python. there is no way to get the "list of users liking my page" though.

Comment: It is possible to use the API using _anything_ that “speaks HTTP”, because that is basically all you need to communicate with it.

Comment: @luschn Thanks. The list of users was accessible a few years ago, do you know why it is impossible now ?

Comment: are you sure it was accessible? anyway, there are many stackoverflow threads about it already. probably for privacy reasons, you don´t need their data anyway. you should also read the platform policy before starting with any programming.

Comment: Not sure about facebook but it was for Instagram which is the "same" company, and it is no longer available for Instagram since a few month since they migrated to Instagram Graph API... I will look into private APIs if you know some feel free to share them :)

Comment: what do you mean with "private API"? there is only the graph api to access page data on facebook. what is the exact use case, if i may ask? what do you want to do with the information? knowing the specifics would make a correct answer easier.

Comment: I saw some APIs simulating a real connections to your account like [this one for instagram](https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python), allowing you to get data that you couldn't access with the offical API. What I want to do is get the name of people liking my page or my posts and link them to my customers database to know who is'nt a customer yet

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook. if there is no way with the official APIs, don´t do it. also, rule of thumb: no data without specific authorization of each user. in other words: data of users (who like your page) is none of your business, unless they allow to to use their data.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current Facebook Graph API does not allow you to access personal information about users so you won't be able to get the names of people liking your page or your posts.